# write text file line by line python

Tags: python, text

I have gotten stuck on something, I want to create a text file line by line using a DB query.  But I want to format the text so it looks like the following:

Data

```
Name        Location
James        Germany
Gail         US
Merkel       Poland
```

I want it to look like this

```
Name=James
Location=Germany

Name=Gail
Location=US

Name=Merkel
Location=Poland
```

I know how to do a csv file and such but I have never heard of creating a file like this, I don't even know what format its called.

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Just `open()` the file, and `write()` formatted lines to it. Try something, and if you're having trouble, ask a more specific question. This is very simple to do, so looking for some magic library or function will be a total waste of your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `Names` and `Locations` as a list, you can do this:

```
data = [('James','Germany'), ('Gail','US'), ('Merkel','Poland')]
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    for name,place in data:
        f.write("Name=%s\nLocation=%s\n\n" % (name, place))
```